# Is there an event for clicking any button from the group?

Tags: c++, events, button, mfc

Lets say that I have a group of several buttons. Is there any event responsible for checking, if a button from the group has been clicked ?

I know I can do it like this:

```
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_1, &CGateDlg::OnBn1Clicked)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_2, &CGateDlg::OnBn2Clicked)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_3, &CGateDlg::OnBn3Clicked)
```

but I want to keep it "DRY", so now I need an event handler that would handle a group of buttons in one function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Kamil : Just make sure your control IDs are consecutive.

Comment: @KamilN. Not exactly consecutive but contiguous :)